# Convert JavaScript object to array to be inserted into relational DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I am using Nodejs. I need to store a JavaScript object in a relational database. Each key in the JavaScript object represents column name in DB. I have following:

```
var data = {
  "aa": "99",
  "bb": ["11","22"],
  "cc": ["44","55","66"]
}
```

I want to convert this object into an array as follow:

```
  data =  [
    {
    "aa": "99",
    "bb": "11",
    "cc": "44"
    },
    {
    "aa": "99",
    "bb": "11",
    "cc": "55"
    },
    {
    "aa": "99",
    "bb": "11",
    "cc": "66"
    },
    {
    "aa": "99",
    "bb": "22",
    "cc": "44"
    },
    {
    "aa": "99",
    "bb": "22",
    "cc": "55"
    },
    {
    "aa": "99",
    "bb": "22",
    "cc": "66"
    }
    ]
```

Is there any way to do this ? I guess using recursive we can do it. But could not find any reference in Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach with a combination algorithm.

This solution dies basically iterate through the given data (an array is made out of the object) and inside of the array iterated over the items. In this case, you have an array with three arrays with the items.

```
[
    ["99"],
    ["11","22"],
    ["44","55","66"]
]
```

It starts with the first array and iterates. Here is only one item and the callback of the iteraton check for the part length and if it is equal to the given array length, al item are acually found. This is the cndition to exit the iteration adn to push the collected parts to the result array. (The items are converted to an object in the reduce callback.)

If the part array does not have the needed length, proceed with the next item of the outer array.

Basically the iteration and recusion works as follow

```
part       0      1      2   action
       ------  -----  -----  ---------------
          99                 go to next level
          99     11          go to next level
          99     11     44   push to result, end level 2
          99     11     55   push to result, end level 2
          99     11     66   push to result, end level 2
          99     11          end level 1
          99     22          go to next level
          99     22     44   push to result, end level 2
          99     22     55   push to result, end level 2
          99     22     66   push to result, end level 2
          99     22          end level 1
          99                 end level 0
```

```js
function combine(object) {
    function c(part) {
        array[part.length].forEach(function (a) {
            var p = part.concat(a);
            if (p.length === array.length) {
                result.push(p.reduce(function (r, b, i) {
                    r[keys[i]] = b;
                    return r;
                }, {}));
                return;
            }
            c(p);
        });
    }

    var keys = Object.keys(object),
        array = keys.map(function (k) { return Array.isArray(object[k]) ? object[k] : [object[k]]; }),
        result = [];

    c([]);
    return result;
}

var data = { aa: "99", bb: ["11", "22"], cc: ["44", "55", "66"] },
    result = combine(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Great ! this works, though I did not understand the logic. Thanks for the prompt answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it's ok to use ES6, a generator could be used to iterate through all layers (not necessarily better and not the most readable, but I just like iterators :) )

```js
function flatten(data) {
  const getArr = a => Array.isArray(a) ? a: [a],
    keyData = Object.keys(data).map(k=>({name:k,arr:getArr(data[k])})),
    getobj = function*(i)  {
      for(let p of keyData[i].arr)
          for(let o of i===keyData.length -1 ? [{}] : getobj(i+1)){
             o[keyData[i].name] = p;
                yield o;
            }        
      }
      return [...getobj(0)];    
}


let data = { aa: "99", bb: ["11", "22"], cc: ["44", "55", "66"] };

console.log(flatten(data));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I guess this will have less time complexity than the other answer given by @Nina, but will this work in node js ??